# How to force some .card-img-overlay content to align at bottom?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a series of Bootstrap 4 cards inside columns like this...

[image]

```
<div class="col-6 pb-md-4">
<a href="http://www.example.com/link.html" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0">
  <img class="card-img" style="opacity: .25" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/w_500,h_350,c_thumb,g_faces/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/cnn-thumbnail-4-1024x576.jpg" alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h4 class="card-title">Charged News Environment Powering Marketing Engagement: CNN’s Andrew Morse</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
    <span class="badge badge-danger font-weight-normal mr-2">Executive Views</span>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```

How could I align the paragraph and the badge to the bottom of the card, whilst keeping the header aligned to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/) on the card overlay. `d-flex flex-column` on the overlay. Then `mt-auto` to push the paragraph to the bottom.

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 pb-md-4">
            <a href="https://www.beet.tv/2019/01/cnn.html" class="card bg-dark text-white shadow-sm border-0">
                <img class="card-img" style="opacity: .25" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/w_500,h_350,c_thumb,g_faces/http://www.contexthq.com/wp-content/uploads/cnn-thumbnail-4-1024x576.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Charged News Environment Powering Marketing Engagement: CNN’s Andrew Morse</h4>
                    <p class="card-text mt-auto">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
                    <span class="badge badge-danger font-weight-normal mr-2">Executive Views</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/dJxBV5rDhv

Comment: Thanks. So, first make `.card-img-overlay` flexbox, including `.align-items-start`, which forces the contents up to the top? Except that you then force the paragraph to the bottom with auto margin-top? To clarify - even though we only push the _paragraph_ down using `.mt-auto`, the element beneath (badge) it is thusly *also* pushed down? Also, it's interesting to note that, without .align-items-start on `.card-img-overlay`, the badge goes full-width

Comment: That's correct. And since the flexbox default is `align-items:stretch`, `align-items-start` is needed.

Comment: Ah-hah. Thanks for clarifying. Good answer.